# ImageButton crashes when trying to play a sound

Tags: android, events, audio, media-player, imagebutton

When trying to make a sound when clicked on an ImageButton my application crashes and I've been staring at my code for quite some time now without finding an answer. I was hoping you guys could help me see what I'm doing wrong.

I tried to make the onClick event manually with the imageButton which failed and then I tried it through the drag and drop system of Eclipse, which made the button clickable through a method I named test123 via the main.xml.

I'll post my code and hope you guys can find a sollution.

Thanks in advance,

```
package com.example.Jeffrey;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Jeffrey extends Activity {
MediaPlayer mp;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.noise);

   // View rakker = findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    //rakker.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void test123()
{        
    mp.start();

}
```

}

The xml that goes with the code:

```
<ImageButton 
android:src="@drawable/rakker" 
android:layout_height="250px" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:onClick="test123"></ImageButton>
```

Comment: Any chance we could see the debug log? please :0)

Comment: Not sure if these represent the log files for my error (new to Eclipse)
roid.ide.eclipse.adt 2 0 2011-08-11 18:29:32.705
!MESSAGE AndroidManifest: Ignoring unknown 'Image' XML element

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 2 0 2011-08-11 18:29:32.977
!MESSAGE AndroidManifest: Ignoring unknown 'ImageBu' XML element

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 2 0 2011-08-11 18:29:33.241
!MESSAGE AndroidManifest: Ignoring unknown 'ImageButt' XML element

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2011-08-11 18:50:13.170
!MESSAGE Referenced part does not exist yet: org.eclipse.ui.views.ProblemView.

Comment: Hmm sorry about the comment losing it's annotations and spaces. No idea why that happened :|

Comment: oh it's just how stack overflow works... it's all good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably worth checking for a null value considering it returns that if for any reason it fails to create the MediaPlayer object. Also, it should probably get released when finished (also with a null check).

EDIT:

while my earlier answer might be worth considering, it is definitely necessary that you have your onClick method take a View as a parameter.

```
//at the top of the file

import android.view.View;

public void test123(View v){
    //v is the view that has been clicked (the ImageButton from your .xml file)
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Agreed on the view, but in this case I'm not using an onClick event to handle my ImageButton but a custom method that is called by the xml command: android:onClick="test123". . . . I've tried giving a View as a parameter but Eclipse gives me a debug error 
("View cannot be resolved to a type")

Comment: were you sure to import android.view.View ? (though I think that should've been automatically prompted)

Comment: Haven't, added it to Eclipse but Eclipse warned me it's not being used. Still tested it without results though

Comment: whatdyu mean added it to Eclipse? (sorry to be thick) You put an import statement at the top of your activity class? and you used View as a parameter in the method? Maybe editting my answer a bit might clear some confusion, one sec.

Comment: hehe Yes I ment an import statement at the top of my javafile. In my method I used zero parameters, since Eclipse tells me a View parameter isn't right.  Sorry if I'm not that clear, kinda new to Android programming and it's environment. :)

Comment: ahhh Yes, how stupid... Eclipse stopped bugging my when I indeed imported the view libraries. Let's see if it works atm

Comment: Oh it's all good, I'm new enough :p Just trying to make sure I don't confuse you (or myself) when trying to help you fix stuff... I edited my answer btw

Comment: I just commented the mediaplayer out of my code and the code started working just fine so I guess the problem lies in there, but stil... where?

Answer (score 1):

Based on code put up in the poset, I could say that issue is related to MediaPlayer usage. MediaPlayer has several states, idle, initialized, prepared, started etc.

In your code, You create the media player object by passing resource id; making media player enter initialized state from idle. Next you need to invoke prepare(). But you are calling start(). May be this is causing the crash.

The MediaPlayer's state transition is neatly explained in android developer website. ([Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html))

Shash

Answer (score 1):

prepare the MediaPlayer with mp.prepare(); before calling mp.start();